# Best approximation with unknown basis functions

Tags: optimization, approximation, least-squares, spline

Given an analytic real known function such as $f(x)=\exp(-x^2)$ defined on a finite interval such as $x \in [0,1]$, find the solution of the following problem
$$\min_{c_k,\phi_k(x)} \int_a^b|e(x)|^2 dx$$
where the error is defined as,
$$e(x) = f(x) - \sum_{k=1}^N c_k\phi_k(x)$$
where $c_k$ are constants and $\phi_k(x)$ are a number of $N$ real basis functions. The restrictions made on the basis functions are as follows,

- $\phi_k(x)$ are piecewise polynomials (splines) with a degree at most $<M$.
- $\phi_k(x)$ are all continuous.
- first derivative of $\phi_k(x)$ should be continuous.
- higher order derivatives of $\phi_k(x)$ of any order greater than 1 need not to be continuous.
- $\phi_k(x)$ are allowed to be non-zero on the whole domain.

**NOTE** that this is not an ordinary least squares problem. Because the basis functions are unknown as well as the constants.

Comment: I would just explicitly define $\phi$ so that all the basis functions are known. I don't think this is tractable in its current form.

Comment: @dgadjov Yes, I should have asked about the best spline not the basis functions, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sum_{k=1}^N c_k \phi_k$ satisfies all the conditions you impose: it is $C^1$ spline.  So the whole problem is to simply find the best $L^2(a,b)$-approximation of $f$ using a piecewise spline.

- If the breakpoints for polynomial "pieces", i.e., knots, are given, simply determine the basis for the  spline space and you are back to the standard least squares problem.
- If the number of knots is not given, then the problem is ill-posed, unless $f$ itself is a spline of the kind you are interested in.  Indeed, one could simply keep subdividing the interval $[a,b]$ into smaller and smaller pieces to eventually drive the error to $0$.

Comment: I understood. I had to ask this way: Given a function, what is the best approximation spline with N number of variable knots and with degree <M.

Comment: If the knots are fixed, we simply solve a linear least squares problem to find the expansion coefficients in terms of B-splines.  If the knots are variable, the least-squares problem becomes nonlinear.  The delicate question is what happens, when knots "collide".  My gut feeling this will not happen for "nice" (for example analytic) $f$.  But I do not think there is a closed form answer to this question, I would solve the problem numerically.

Comment: Exactly, the optimization problem becomes very complicated. I tried to formulate the problem, but I thought there would be good literature in the subject of "meshing" and "Curve approximation" using shape functions or b-splines; however, I could not find a reference to my problem.